# Erro "zero is not a supported scheme"

Tags: python, couchdb

Estou tentando usar o CouchDB juntamente com o Python, fiz a instalação dos dois corretamente, fui até o CouchDBe criei um usuário, quando vou para o compilador do Python e executo:

```
import couchdb 
couch = couchdb.Server('zero:central@http://localhost:5984')
db = couch.create('test')
```

obtenho o seguinte erro,

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 207, in create
>     self.resource.put_json(name)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 570, in put_json
>     **params)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 585, in _request_json
>     headers=headers, **params)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 581, in _request
>     credentials=self.credentials)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 289, in request
>     conn = self.connection_pool.get(url)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 505, in get
>     raise ValueError('%s is not a supported scheme' % scheme)
> ValueError: zero is not a supported scheme
> ```

Já pesquisei bastante, mas ainda n obtive nenhuma ideia da solução concreta para isso.

Answer (score 1):

No código que fiz acima, no momento em que setei os dados do superuser + url de conexão não me atentei na posição do http://

Errado:

```
zero:central@http://localhost:5984
```

o correto seria :

```
http://zero:central@localhost:5984
```